# Borland C++ stretch a TAnimate

Tags: c++, c++builder

Hi I have an application made with Borland C++Builder. I am using RAD Studio for it.

In the application there is a TForm with a TAnimate (object for videos) on it. I wanted to know if it is somehow possible to stretch the TAnimate object?

If I change the size of the object:

```
video->Width = newwidth;
video->Height = newheight;
```

The video doesn't get stretched but a white border gets added to the video image.

Is there some way to scale the video image?

If someone tells me that it is impossible that would be ok !

Maybe it is possible to convert TAnimate in a scaled TImage.

The autosize property of TAnimate doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TAnimate` is just a thin wrapper around a Win32 [Animation control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761881.aspx), which has no option for stretching/scaling video.  Even MSDN says:

> Note  The AVI file, or resource, must not have a sound channel. **The capabilities of the animation control are very limited** and are subject to change. If you need a control to provide multimedia playback and recording capabilities for your application, you can use the MCIWnd control. For more information, see [MCIWnd Window Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd798215.aspx).